# Swift 3: Get Value from Array[Int] in UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview

I have an Array like this `[1, 2, 3, 4]` sometime `[1, 2, 4]` .

I want to implement hide and show a `UITableViewCell` in Dinamic data. But i get a problem with getting the element of Array. I'm using `for` loop but its seems doesnt work. Below my code :

```
var dataChgSort = [ ["sort" : 0 , "chgSort" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ] ,
                                ["sort" : 1, "chgSort" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ] ] ,
                                ["sort" : 12, "chgSort" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ] ,
                                ["sort" : 2, "chgSort" : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] ] ,
                                ["sort" : 3, "chgSort" : [4, 5] ] ,
                                ["sort" : 4, "chgSort" : [1, 3, 8, 4, 5] ] ,
                                ["sort" : 8, "chgSort" : [3, 8] ] ,
                                ["sort" : 5, "chgSort" : [1, 3, 4, 5] ] ,
                                ["sort" : 6, "chgSort" : [1, 2, 3] ]
                            ]
.....
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    var height: CGFloat = 0

    let dataRow = ((self.dataChgSort[index] as [String: Any] )["chgSort"] as! [Int]) /*Dinamic Array int [1, 2, 3] or [1,3] etc*/

    self.chgSort = ?????

    if indexPath.row == self.chgSort  {
        height = 0
    } else {
        height = super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
    }
    return height
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding that if your `dataRow` show "[1, 2, 4]", so tableview will show height for row 1, 2 and 4. Below is my solution to check if `indexPath.row` occur in the selected array.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    let dataRow = ((self.dataChgSort[index] as [String: Any] )["chgSort"] as! [Int]) /*Dinamic Array int [1, 2, 3] or [1,3] etc*/

    if dataRow.containse(indexPath.row + 1)  {
       return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)

    } 
    return 0
}
```

Comment: wow its work, but there is a mistmatch with display. I think the index always start with 0 but i will fix it. Thank You

Comment: @MarioMargoPradipta great! I update the answer to have the + 1